# How can i check if a variable is inside a range of numbers in a parameterized JUnit Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, parameterized

I am creating a worksheet about language models for a course called "Information Retrieval". The students should be able to check if their code produces the correct answers so i set up a couple of Junit Tests which checks a number of cases. Because i wanted to include multiple test-cases i decided to use parameterized Junit Tests. (I followed this example: http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/)
I want to test a function which returns a float which can be **within** a range of numbers. If I would be testing two floats i would be able to use

`assertEquals(float expected, float actual, float delta)`

where the delta is the range.
But because I am using parameterized Tests I have to work with Objects

`assertEquals(Object expected, Object actual)`

These Objects are Lists which contain Floats, but in the Code they are just Objects so Solutions like these do not work:

`assertEquals(Object expected, Object actual, float delta)` (this method does not exist)

`assertTrue(Math.abs(Object expected - Object actual)<ERROR_MARGIN)` (Operator '-' undefined for Object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own method that does the comparison, and have that return true or false

```
assertTrue(objectsAreInRange(actual, expected, delta));

boolean objectsAreInRange(Object actual, Object expected, float delta){
...
}
```

Comment: `assertInRange(message, expected, delta, actual)` for better error message and Junit argument ordering.

Comment: Of course. Thank you that solves it very easily. Also: That was fast.

Answer (score 0):

User already gave an answer but if you need special Asserts just extend Assert and write your own implementation:

```
public class OwnAssert extends Assert {

    public static void assertEqualsList(Object listOfFloatExpected, Object listOFFloatActual, float delta){
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static assertInRange(String message, float expected, float delta, float actual) {
   if (delta < 0) {
     delta = -delta;
   }
   if (actual < expected - delta)
     Assert.fail(message + actual + " is less than " + expected + " - " + delta);
   if (actual > expected + delta) 
     Assert.fail(message + actual + " is more than " + expected + " + " + delta);
}

public static assertInRange(float expected, float delta, float actual) {
  assertInRange(expected, delta, actual);
}
```

Keep argument order consistent with Junit convention, provide most complete error message possible.